# Static ARP Entries aren't being added

Tags: arp, windows-command-prompt, mac-address, static-routes

So I'm trying to create a static ARP Entry with the ip and MAC Address of my router. I'm currently using admin command prompt and the command arp -s [ip] [mac address], but it isn't working. Every time I check the table with arp -a, I just see the ip and mac address under an interface (there are two) with type dynamic. How do I set up the static entry? Also, can anyone clear up to me what the interfaces are? (I'm kind of a tech noob lol)
Edit: To clarify, this is windows 10

Here are some pictures:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsEg7.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDF5d.png

Comment: Screenshots would be helpful.

Comment: Okay, should i blur anything out or can i just take them

Comment: If you're dealing with non-public IP addresses, then there is nothing to hide.

Comment: Why are you trying to create a static ARP entry for your router?

Comment: Okay, I added Pictures.

Comment: Those screenshots don't show anything. Please show the `arp -s` input and the response.

Answer (score -1):

Try
Netsh -c interface ipv4 add neighbours "your connection type" "your ip" "Mac address of your router" store=persistent

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure about the `arp -s` command, but I am doing it using `/etc/ethers` file
I've put static entries like these :

```
root@r2w:~# cat /etc/ethers  
b4:2e:99:1b:60:97 193.355.204.2
```

and then doing `arp -f /etc/ethers`
which replaces arp table with those manual entries

Comment: Hi, Is this for windows or linux?

Comment: for linux of course, there is no /etc/ directory on windows

Comment: oof. I was asking for a windows laptop lol